# Creating Methods in Java (Beginner)

Tags: java, methods

I am pretty new to Java so I apologize if my question is pretty basic. What I'm struggling with is creating a method. There is already an object called "robot" and a method called turnLeft();. I would like to create a new method called turnRight();. I tried doing this by writing something like:

```
public void turnRight(Robot robot) {
      robot.turnLeft();
      robot.turnLeft();
      robot.turnLeft();

   }
```

Something seems to be wrong since I cannot call for that method, what is it that is missing? I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

/Nick

Comment: Post the entire class please.

Comment: Is `turnRight` part of the `Robot` class? If so, you probably don't need to accept a different robot class as a parameter.

Comment: As previously pointed out, though, please post the entire class so that we can be sure that we're addressing where you're stuck.

Comment: How do you want to call the method?

Comment: This is the class which I am editing in (I skipped posting some code not related to this): 
public class MazeFinder { private Robot robot; 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      MazeFinder finder = new MazeFinder(); 
      finder.createEnviroment(); 
      finder.findExit(); 
   } 

But then there's another java-file with the class robot (which I am not allowed to edit). 

I would like to call the method by writing: robot.turnAround();

Comment: You need to extend the class robot to do that. Or you could do turnAround(robot) the same way you did with turnRight

Comment: Can you [edit] the code into the question? It's not really readable in the comments, plus comments really aren't for adding information to the question in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I remember this question from Intro to Java.

Your class is static, that's why you can't access it.

Try changing to

```
public static void turnRight(Robot robot) {
      robot.turnLeft();
      robot.turnLeft();
      robot.turnLeft();

   }
```

And see if that works.

Comment: If you remember the question, can you edit it into the OP's question so that it makes more sense to other readers? Right now, I'm not really sure how to vote on this answer because I don't have enough context to know whether it's addressing the OP's problem or not.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work anyway. I get this error: MazeFinder.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
            robot.turnAround();
                 ^
  symbol:   method turnAround()
  location: variable robot of type Robot
1 error

Comment: @Nickewas we talked about turnRight not turnAround, that's an entirely different method

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica please see edit to the Q

Comment: Sorry, I tried creating that method too (with one less robot.turnLeft()) the exact same way but got the same error message, sorry for sending the wrong error message here

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if i got your question, but this is what you can do:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Robot roboCop = new Robot();
        System.out.println("Please turn left");
        roboCop.turnLeft();
        System.out.println("Please turn right");
        roboCop.turnRight();
    }
}

class Robot {
    public void turnLeft()
    {
        System.out.println("turned left");
    }

    public void turnRight() {
        turnLeft();
        turnLeft();
        turnLeft();
        System.out.println("turned left three times, am i right?");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your methods I mean turn.right or also turn.left don't return anything and just turn left you should write the function with void like this

```
           public static void turnRight(Robot robot) {
                  robot.turnLeft( );
                  robot.turnLeft( );
                  robot.turnLeft( );
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

make the method static, like the following

```
public static void turnRight(Robot robot) {
    robot.turnLeft();
    robot.turnLeft();
    robot.turnLeft();
}
```

then when calling it make sure you are not doing this
`robot.turnRight()`
instead do
`turnRight(robot)`

Comment: Thanks! Changing to static and turnRight(robot) worked. How would I be able to write the code so that I can write robot.turnRight() the same way I can write robot.turnLeft()?

Comment: in short, you cannot, unless you make a new class extending robot, you aren't meant to insert your own methods into it, because that could cause problems. There are some languages like Kotlin, that allow you to make extension methods, but that isn't possible in Java. The only alternative is making a class extend Robot, then adding that method, then make an instance of that class instead and using it, but that's not worth it for this, so I'd stick with just using the static method.